# accessing Dictionary from different programs

Tags: python, dictionary, python-daemon

I am creating dictionary out of a large file.

```
def make_dic():
    big_dic={}
    for foo in open(bar):
           key,value=do_something(foo)
           big_dic[key]=value
def main():
    make_dic() #this takes time
```

I have to access this dictionary many times but from completely different programs. It takes lot of time to read this file and make dictionary. Is it possible to make a dictionary which remains in memory even if one program exits???? So that I create it once but can use it again  and again from different programs....

Comment: What are the types of the dictionary's keys and values?

Comment: Would a database server such as MySQL be suitable?

Comment: Would it be an option to simply join all those "programs" to a single program, performing all necessary tasks without exiting?

Comment: @Sven Marnach It is not possible to join all then in a single program. Also it makes debugging very lazy :(

Comment: @SvenMarnach key values are simple text (key is date/time values are some text)

Comment: How about making this make_dic a service and let other programs requesting the dictionary through RPC? ex, jsonrpc~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work for all situations that fit your description, but [`cPickle`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-cPickle) should help with speed.

The only problem I can think of is that combining data persistence with IPC is tough. So if these different programs are modifying the dictionary at the same time, `pickle` won't help. Another approach might be to use a database...

I like [Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9315722/577088)'s suggestion, but there are some tradeoffs worth considering. Some setup...

```
>>> pickle_file = open('pickle_foo', 'w')
>>> anydbm_file = anydbm.open('anydbm_foo', 'c')
>>> d = dict((str(i), str(j)) for i, j in zip(range(999999, -1, -1), range(0, 1000000)))
```

Obviously populating the `anydbm_file` will be pretty slow:

```
>>> %timeit for k, v in d.iteritems(): anydbm_file[k] = v
1 loops, best of 3: 5.14 s per loop
```

The time is comparable to the time it takes to dump and load a pickle file:

```
>>> %timeit cPickle.dump(d, pickle_file)
1 loops, best of 3: 3.79 s per loop
>>> pickle_file.close()
>>> pickle_file = open('pickle_foo', 'r')
>>> %timeit d = cPickle.load(pickle_file)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.03 s per loop
```

But the `anydbm_file` you only have to create once; then, opening it again is nigh-instantaneous.

```
>>> %timeit anydbm_file = anydbm.open('anydbm_foo', 'r')
10000 loops, best of 3: 74.3 us per loop
```

So `anydbm` has the advantage there. On the other hand,

```
>>> %timeit for i in range(1, 1000): x = anydbm_file[str(i)]
100 loops, best of 3: 3.15 ms per loop
>>> %timeit for i in range(1, 1000): x = d[str(i)]
1000 loops, best of 3: 374 us per loop
```

Reading a key from `anydbm_file` takes ten times longer than reading a key from a dictionary in memory. You'd have to do a lot of lookups for this difference to outweigh the 5 seconds necessary for a pickle dump/load cycle; but even if you don't, the difference in read times here could lead to sluggish performance, depending on what you're doing.

Other options are [`SQLite3`](http://docs.python.org/library/sqlite3.html) or (for a separate database server process that allows connections from multiple processes running concurrently), [`psycopg2`](http://initd.org/psycopg/) + [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/).

Comment: Really nice analysis, and a pity that nobody seems to be looking.   What database is backing `anydbm` on your system?  This will have a huge impact on performance, especially if it happens to be `dumbdbm`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach, `whichdb.whichdb('f.db')` -> `bdsdb185`.

Comment: Thanks.  According to the `anydb` docs, bsddb is tried first, so it seems to be reputed to be the fastest one.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to make a dictionary with keys and values being strings persistent is Python's [`anydbm`](http://docs.python.org/library/anydbm.html) module.  You can basically create a file that acts like a dictionary mapping strings to strings.

Comment: +1 -- that's one of those back-of-the-shelf modules I always forget about. But how much faster is it than pickle? Perhaps I'll do some timings when I get a chance...